# @property not accept length in em unit

Tags: html, css, css-variables, css-houdini

NOTE: The MRE might not work in some browsers due to the [poor support table](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40property).

```css
@property --width1 {
  syntax: '<length>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 20em;
}

@property --width2 {
  syntax: '<length>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 200px;
}

div {
  margin: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#div1 { width: var(--width1); }
#div2 { width: 20em;          }
#div3 { width: var(--width2); }
#div4 { width: 200px;         }
```

```html
<div id="div1">var(--width1) = 20em</div>
<div id="div2">20em</div>
<div id="div3">var(--width2) = 200px</div>
<div id="div4">200px</div>
```

In `px`, width of `div3` is same as `div4` as expected.

In `em`, `div2`'s width was as expected. But in `div1`, it is almost as if the `var(--width1)` is ignored and the width is set to `auto`. Any way for the `var(--width1)` to work as expected?

Comment: As you told in your post - it's **experimental** feature, so do not expect it to work properly

Comment: @Justinas Means I need to stick with old manual form of changing width :( Isn't there an article related to this topic?

Comment: you cannot use relative unit there (you can also try with percentage it won't work). Unfortunately the Spec page is down right now to give you an answer: https://drafts.css-houdini.org/css-properties-values-api-1/#at-property-rule

Comment: @TemaniAfif you can use percentage. If you change the data-type to `length-percentage` or just `percentage` . Not sure why `em` doesn't work  because as you can see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#units `em` are among `length` data type accepted units.

Comment: @MihaiT it's a length but it's a *relative* one. I always faced issue with them inside the initial value. You can try with `vw`, `ch`, etc. The behavior is a bit random sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the specification](https://drafts.css-houdini.org/css-properties-values-api-1/#initial-value-descriptor):

> The `initial-value` must be **computationally independent**.

and

> A property value is computationally independent if it can be converted into a computed value using only the value of the property on the element, and "global" information that cannot be changed by CSS.

In your case, `em` depend on the `font-size` value so it's not *computationally independent*

Comment: Would be good to hear your thoughts on this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68882689/3597276