# Select every second element of a series of nested elements (each has only one child)

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Does a css selector exist that will target every second `.letter`?

Of course, I could have put all `.letter` elements on the same level and used `:nth-child(2n)`, but they all depend on the position of the former letter, so I need the nestedness.

```css
.firstname {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 75px 0 0 75px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.letter {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.2);
}
.letter > div {
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstname">
  <div class="letter s">S
    <div class="letter e">E
        <div class="letter b">B
           <div class="letter a">A
             <div class="letter s2">S
               <div class="letter t">T
                 <div class="letter i">I
                   <div class="letter a2">A
                     <div class="letter n">N</div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: to select and do what? the selector doesn't exist but if you give us what you are trying to achieve, we can probably find a solution without the selector you are looking for

Comment: @TemaniAfif E.g. color any second letter red. Of course, I could then add a class to every second element, but that is very tedious. Also, If I at a later time should want to add another letter to the list of nested letters, I would then have to rewrite a lot of classes -- even more tedious. So I really don't want to go that way.

Comment: is it only about coloration? I am asking because we can probably find solutions (without adding classes) based on a specific cases (not in general)

Comment: @TemaniAfif It's about being able to apply some style to every x-th nested child of that nested structure of letters. Could be coloration, polygonization, border, box-shadow, etc., whatever I happen to settle on. I am just playing around trying to create some artistic and I find myself missing this ability as it would make everything so much easier -- as opposed to the more tedious alternatives I mentioned.

Comment: So it's impossible. Either you add classes or you write a long CSS selectors like the answer below (that you can generate using SASS to make it easy)

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to play with *only* coloration here is a trick using `filter` where the idea is to use a `180deg` hue-rotation to get back to the initial color after two iterations. This will simulate your selector.

It remains limited as solution because you will need to tweak the filter to have the coloration you want which is not a trivial task

```css
.firstname {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 75px 0 0 75px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.letter {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
  color:red;
  filter: hue-rotate(180deg) saturate(2);
}

.letter>div {
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstname">
  <div class="letter s">S
    <div class="letter e">E
      <div class="letter b">B
        <div class="letter a">A
          <div class="letter s2">S
            <div class="letter t">T
              <div class="letter i">I
                <div class="letter a2">A
                  <div class="letter n">N</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the `saturate(2)` here? Is this to show that this method is indeed limited? That filter will add up at each level, so because of it you won't actually come back to the initial color.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately CSS doesn't have a single selector for grand children.

You'd need manually create a selector structure:

```
.firstname > .letter > .letter,
.firstname > .letter > .letter > .letter > lettter,
.firstname > .letter > .letter > .letter > lettter > .letter > lettter
{
/* style */
}
```